# how to navigate between selectors that don't have a selector using next / previous

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown which I'm trying to make into something like a google suggest. I looked at jQuery Autocomplete but I wanted to see if I coudl make our 
current solution work (done by a different developer). We are populating a autocomplete-results dropdown like the following:

```
<ul id="autocomplete-results">
  <li class="auto-li category">TAGS</li>
  <li class="auto-li">red wine</li>
  <li class="auto-li">french wine</li>
  <li class="auto-li category">LOCATIONS</li>
  <li class="auto-li">Joe's Restaurant</li>
  <li class="auto-li">Noodle Express</li>
</ul>
```

and this renders fine. Where there is a keydown event, checkKey is run. The logic I would like to have is that it goes to the first auto-li class which doesn't have a category class.
But navigating with this not syntax isn't working correctly. This is just a syntax issue as removing `category` causes everything to work ok.

How would I make it so that it is able to jump from 'red wine' to Joes Restaurant?

```
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
....
function checkKey(e){
if(e.keyCode==40){
  if($('.auto-li-hover').length > 0){
    var $that=$('.auto-li-hover');
    $that.next('.auto-li:not(.category)').addClass('auto-li-hover')
    $that.removeClass('auto-li-hover');
  }else{
    //alert('NO auto-li-hover');
    // ###
    $('.auto-li:first:not(.category)').addClass('auto-li-hover'); // this doesn't add this class correctly
  }
}
```

Comment: actually, your `.next ... not ...` looks fine. What is the error?

Comment: well, it doesn't give me a runtime error - it just doesn't find that first element (ie the else statment). So the part with the commented three #'s

Answer (score 1):

I would switch the order in `not` and `first`, cuz that might get first `li` with class `.auto-li` then the `li` which is NOT `.category`, in this case, no `li` is left.

So, try this:

```
function checkKey(e){
if(e.keyCode==40){
  if($('.auto-li-hover').length > 0){
    var selectables = $('#autocomplete-results li:not(.category)');
    var current = $('.auto-li-hover');
    var i = selectables.index(current);

    if(i==selectables.length - 1)
        i = 0;
    current.removeClass('auto-li-hover');
    selectables.eq(++i).addCLass('auto-li-hover');
  }else{
    //alert('NO auto-li-hover');
    // ###
    $('.auto-li:not(.category):first').addClass('auto-li-hover'); // this doesn't add this class correctly
  }
}
```

Comment: hey Marcus, you were right on the first issue. now is there a way to jump from French Wine -> Joe's?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
//....
function checkKey(e){
    if(e.keyCode==40){
        if($('.auto-li-hover').length > 0){
            var $that=$('.auto-li-hover');
            $that.removeClass('auto-li-hover');   
            var continueNext = true;

            while(continueNext ){
                $next = $that.next('.auto-li');
                if($next.length > 0 && $next.hasClass('category')){  
                    $that = $next ;
                }else if($next.length > 0){
                    continueNext= false;
                }
            }
        }else{
            //alert('NO auto-li-hover');
            // ###
            $('.auto-li:first:not(.category)').addClass('auto-li-hover'); // this doesn't add this class correctly
        }
    }
```

I think this would help you. I din't test it.